# how to toggle one button and one button only in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle one button using jQuery. So far, all of the information I have found is to toggle a paragraph, for instance, using another button, but I want to make this button appear and reappear when it is clicked. I also want to increase the "score" when the shown button is clicked, and decrease the "score" when the button reappears (after the user clicks it). Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I have a series of buttons, but I will link the code for one of them for now.

```
HTML: 
<li><button id="active1" onclick="disappear1()"></button></li>

JavaScript:
function disappear1() {
  $("#active1").toggle();
  currentStreak++;
  document.getElementById("streak").innerHTML="current streak: " + currentStreak;
}
```

I know that the problem is that when I click on the button, the button disappears so there's no way for me to find it again. I want there to be a way to still reference it.

Comment: You can still reference it (the same way), but you'll need to click on something else. What that is is up to you.

Comment: you mean fade out, delay then fade in?

Answer (score 0):

The .toggle() function changes the targeted element's CSS display property to hide/show the element. When the element is hidden it is still in the DOM and can still be targeted with same method as when it's visible.

The example below toggles an element with an ID of 'active1' when a button is clicked. Even when the 'active1' element is hidden it is still referenced and made visible again.

```
$('#button1').click( function (){
  $('#active1').toggle();
});
```

Comment: how do i name a button "button1"?

Comment: also, i just tried this and it didn't seem to work because the button disappeared so when I clicked it again, there was nothing there.

Comment: You want the user to click a button after it has been hidden? The example above is to toggle the display of a button using another button.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do. This is because I want to give the user the option to make the button reappear if they've changed their mind.

Comment: I would suggest implementing a new cancel button that shows when the user click the first button to give them the option to cancel. Getting the user to click an invisible button is bad UX